# Brew httpd service status shows none Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, homebrew, httpd.conf, ubuntu-20.04

I installed apache2 httpd via brew. Installation went fine. I started the service with **brew services start httpd** No error. Says service started. But when I check using **brew services list** the httpd service status shows none.

I tried reinstalling. First I uninstalled httpd. Then I removed the folder /httpd with sudo -rm -rf. Then reinstalled. But the problem persists.

```
dheeraj@Dh33raj-Ubuntu:~$ brew services start httpd
==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.httpd)
dheeraj@Dh33raj-Ubuntu:~$ brew services list
Name  Status  User    File
httpd none    dheeraj 
mysql started dheeraj ~/.config/systemd/user/homebrew.mysql.service
php   started dheeraj ~/.config/systemd/user/homebrew.php.service
dheeraj@Dh33raj-Ubuntu:~$
```